# Llenar una matriz de n*m de forma diagonal

Tags: java, matrices

Poseo un problema que involucra matrices, lo que necesito hacer es llenar una matriz de N*M de dimensión (es decir, de un número n de columnas y filas dados por el usuario), con números pares.
ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me he venido arriba con el código, pero no logro hacer que la serie vaya incrementandose diagonalmente, ademas cuando la matriz es cuadrada(4*4 ejemplo) el programa corre normalmente), pero caso contrario, si es de n*m(lo que se solicita, tengo el despliegue y un error. Aparte, la serie debe de comenzar desde la parte superior derecha(lo cual ya logre), y terminar en la parte inferior derecha(pero con la sucesion de pares en forma diagonal)
¿Como puedo hacer que la serie de numeros pares se genera de manera diagonal exactamente como en el ejemplo anterior?
Mi codigo:

```
    int val;
    int lonv;
    int fil;
    int col;
    int su=2;
    int matriz[][];
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nro de filas para la matriz: ");
    fil=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nro de columnas para la matriz: ");
    col=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    matriz=new int [fil][col];
    for(int i=0; i<fil; i++)
    {
        for(int j=(col-1); j>=0; j-- )
        {
            if(matriz[i][j]<= 2)
            {
                matriz[i][j]= su;
                su+=2;
            }
            else
            {

                System.out.println("");
                matriz[i][j]= su;
                su+=2;
            }

        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<col; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Dejo la corrida del codigo para cada caso:

*Corrida del programa con matriz cuadrada(errónea)

[image: Corrida del programa con matriz cuadrada(errónea)]

*Corrida del programa con matriz de n*m(errónea)

[image: Corrida del programa con matriz de n*m(errónea)]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo recorrer una matriz en forma diagonal en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/407618/como-puedo-recorrer-una-matriz-en-forma-diagonal-en-java)

Answer (score 4):

Tienes dos errores.

Uno, creo que no has logrado conceptualizar bien el tema de cómo recorrer la matriz en *diagonal*, de la manera que debe realizarse. Yo hice un pequeño ejercicio en papel (bueno en Excel, pero es lo mismo) con una matriz de 2 filas y 3 columnas y pude observar que el orden en el que necesito recorrer la matriz es este:

```
1, 3
1, 2
2, 3
1, 1
2, 2
2, 1
```

Seguro se puede hacer con for, pero se me hace más natural utilizar un `do/while`, por tanto así he pensado mi algoritmo, que sería el siguiente:

Iniciamos pidiendo los datos, esta parte es común, luego:

```
    int filas;
    int columnas;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nro de filas para la matriz: ");
    filas=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nro de columnas para la matriz: ");
    columnas=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    //definimos las variables para almacenar la matriz y de control
    int fila, columna, ultimaColumnaInicio, ultimaFilaInicio;
    int matriz[][];
    int valor = 2;
    matriz = new int[filas][columnas];
```

Versión *larga*, pasito a pasito:

```
    columna = columnas - 1;
    fila = 0;
    ultimaColumnaInicio = columna;
    ultimaFilaInicio = fila;
    do {
      matriz[fila][columna] = valor;
      if (columna == columnas - 1 && ultimaColumnaInicio > 0) {
        fila = 0;
        columna = ultimaColumnaInicio - 1;
        ultimaColumnaInicio = columna;
      } else if (fila == filas - 1 || columna == columnas - 1) {
        fila = ultimaFilaInicio + 1;
        columna = 0;
        ultimaFilaInicio = fila;
      } else {
        fila++;
        columna++;
      }
      valor = valor + 2;
    } while ((fila != filas));
```

Una versión más condensada (menos líneas de código) del algoritmo que llena la matriz sería como esta:

```
    ultimaColumnaInicio = columna = columnas - 1;
    ultimaFilaInicio = fila = 0;
    do {
      matriz[fila++][columna++] = valor;
      if (columna == columnas && ultimaColumnaInicio > 0) {
        fila = 0;
        columna = --ultimaColumnaInicio;
      } else if (fila == filas || columna == columnas) {
        fila = ++ultimaFilaInicio;
        columna = 0;
      }
      valor = valor + 2;
    } while ((fila != filas));
```

Finalmente, tienes un error al momento de imprimir la matriz, ya que utilizas la variable `col` tanto para el iterador de filas como para el de columnas, por ello eleva una excepción cuando la matriz no es cuadrada. La versión correcta sería algo como:

```
    for(int i=0; i < filas; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < columnas; j++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%3d", matriz[i][j]) +" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Esto produce una salida como estas:

Matriz de 4x5

```
 22  14   8   4   2 
 30  24  16  10   6 
 36  32  26  18  12 
 40  38  34  28  20
```

Matriz de 7x5

```
 22  14   8   4   2 
 32  24  16  10   6 
 42  34  26  18  12 
 52  44  36  28  20 
 60  54  46  38  30 
 66  62  56  48  40 
 70  68  64  58  50
```

Comment: El codigo funciona bien

Comment: pero hay un pequeño error

Comment: Me da un: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: Cuando solicito una matriz con filas superiores a las columnas

Comment: Mientras esto no suceda todo da bien

Comment: como podria correguir ese error?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ya está actualizado para contemplar ese caso. Me quedo con la idea, sin embargo, que no has hecho todo el esfuerzo por comprender el funcionamiento del programa. No me lo tomes a mal, pero este no es el rincón del vago punto com. La idea acá es que aprendas y eso siempre conlleva esfuerzo. Quizás puedas ganar esta tarea, o el curso, pero por favor no te engañes a ti mismo.

Comment: No presente esta tarea, la verdadad, solo queria ver como se podia solucionar este tipo de problema, ya que jamas nos dierón alguna explicaciòn, y la solucion simplemente la estaba tratando de realizar por mì mismo, con curiosidad, pero no encontraba la manera. haora que lo eh visto, tengo las cosas por fin mas claras.

Comment: Inclusive, pidiendo ayuda a unos colegas de nivel superior, no supierón guiarme en el problema...

Comment: No obtengo ninguna nota por el codigo, solo conocimiento...

Comment: Eso ya es entre tu y tu conciencia.Si la respuesta te ha sido de utilidad, considera marcarla como la respuesta aceptada, esto ayudará a futuros navegantes a identificar que ha habido un aporte que ha sido de utilidad para resolver el tema. Si no sabes como hacerlo, te invito a hacer el [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Bueno a mi manera de ver el error lo tienes en el recorrido para mostrar la matriz como te muestro a continuación:

```
//Comienzas por las filas y después las columnas
for(int i=0; i<fil; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Tienes que recorrer fila, columna. Espero te resulte