# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer una matriz de forma diagonal en Java?

Tags: java

¡Hola a todos!

Necesito recorrer una matriz en diagonal empezando desde el extremo superior derecho, tal como muestro en la imagen.

He tratado de todas las formas pero se me hace imposible.

Desde ya, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
for (i =0; i>=matriz.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j >=0; j--) {
        System.out.println(matriz[i][j]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: que código tienes actualmente?

Comment: for (i =0; i>=matriz.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j >=0; j--) {
                
                System.out.println(matriz[i][j]);
            }
            
        }

Comment: añádelo a tu pregunta, por favor

Comment: Tú pregunta es similar a esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216229/144064 , dale un vistazo puede ayudarte.

Comment: Basándonos en el ejemplo que pones cual es el resultado que deseas obtener

Comment: 5,4,11,3,1017,2,9,16,23,etc

Comment: la pregunta que te sugiere @user12093177 es suficiente sólo cambia que en lugar de asignar un valor a una posición debes leer y enviar a salida lo que se encuentra el ella.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Llenar una matriz de n\*m de forma diagonal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216147/llenar-una-matriz-de-nm-de-forma-diagonal)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Algoritmo propuesto

1. Recorrer los comienzos de cada diagonal, partiendo de la esquina superior derecha, retrocediendo hasta la esquina superior izquierda, y descendiendo hasta la esquina inferior izquierda.

   Siendo **x** la posición más alta que puede ocupar un elemento en el eje horizontal e **y** la posición más alta que puede ocupar un elemento en el eje vertical, la secuencia sería similar a esta:

   ```java
   horizontal = x, vertical = 0
   ····························
   horizontal = 3, vertical = 0
   horizontal = 2, vertical = 0
   horizontal = 1, vertical = 0

   horizontal = 0, vertical = 0 

   horizontal = 0, vertical = 1
   horizontal = 0, vertical = 2
   horizontal = 0, vertical = 3
   ····························
   horizontal = 0, vertical = y
   ```

   *Nota: no se debe olvidar que los índices de la matriz comienzan en cero, y habría que restar una unidad a los límites de **x** e **y** si se obtienen a partir de las dimensiones de la misma.*

2. Por cada uno de estos comienzos, extraer todos los valores de la diagonal, de arriba abajo y de izquierda a derecha, en paralelo a la diagonal principal.

   Partiendo del comienzo de diagonal para el punto horizontal cero y vertical cero, habría que seguir la siguiente secuencia hasta que se alcance uno de los límites de la matriz:

   ```java
   horizontal = 0, vertical = 0
   horizontal = 1, vertical = 1
   horizontal = 2, vertical = 2
   ····························
   horizontal = x, vertical = y
   ```

Este algoritmo es válido para todo tipo de matrices bidimensionales, tanto cuadradas como rectangulares.

## Fragmento de código

Dada una matriz bidimensional de `w` por `h` elementos llamada `array`, es posible mostrar los valores deseados utilizando este código:

```java
for (int i = 1 - w; i < h; i++)
    for (int x = -min(0, i), y = max(0, i); x < w && y < h; x++, y++)
        System.out.println(array[y][x]);
```

Nótese que el código necesita las funciones [`min(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,int)) y [`max(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,int)), que pueden ser importadas del siguiente modo:

- `import static java.lang.Math.min;`
- `import static java.lang.Math.max;`

Alternativamente, y con fines puramente didácticos, es posible utilizar [operadores condicionales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) para suplir estas funciones:

- `((a < b) ? a : b)` en vez de `min(a, b)`
- `((a > b) ? a : b)` en vez de `max(a, b)`

## Representación gráfica

A continuación se detalla de forma gráfica el proceso a seguir para extraer los valores de la matriz con el algoritmo ya explicado. Las coordenadas señaladas en púrpura (para el eje horizontal) y azul (para el eje vertical) indican el comienzo de cada diagonal determinado por el paso **1** del algoritmo, mientras que las señaladas en amarillo o rojo (para ambos ejes) muestran cada una de las iteraciones del paso **2** del algoritmo; el color rojo señala que se ha alcanzado uno de los límites de la matriz.

[image: Ilustración]

## Código de prueba

```java
import java.lang.Math;

class Diagonal {
    public static void main(String[] argumentos) {

        // Define los números.
        Integer[][] matriz = {
            {  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 },
            {  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11 },
            { 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 },
            { 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 },
            { 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 },
            { 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35 }
        };

        // Calcula la altura y la anchura de la matriz introducida.
        Integer altura = matriz.length, anchura = matriz[0].length;

        for (
            // Recorre los inicios de cada diagonal en los bordes de la matriz.
            Integer diagonal = 1 - anchura; // Comienza con un número negativo.
            diagonal <= altura - 1; // Mientras no llegue a la última diagonal.
            diagonal += 1 // Avanza hasta el comienzo de la siguiente diagonal.
        ) {
            for (
                // Recorre cada una de las diagonales a partir del extremo superior izquierdo.
                Integer vertical = Math.max(0, diagonal), horizontal = -Math.min(0, diagonal);
                vertical < altura && horizontal < anchura; // Mientras no excedan los límites.
                vertical += 1, horizontal += 1 // Avanza en diagonal incrementando ambos ejes.
            ) {
                // Muestra cada punto de la matriz ordenadamente.
                System.out.println(matriz[vertical][horizontal]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Valores de prueba

Una ejecución correcta del programa debería extraer los siguientes valores:

```json
[5, 4, 11, 3, 10, 17, 2, 9, 16, 23, 1, 8, 15, 22, 29, 0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 6, 13, 20, 27, 34, 12, 19, 26, 33, 18, 25, 32, 24, 31, 30]
```

Comment: Y al contrario como seria?, es decir para leer la matriz desde la posición [0][0] hasta la [n][n]?

Comment: Lo más sencillo es que utilices `array[y][w-1-x]` en vez de `array[y][x]`