# Matriz en diagonal en JAVA

Tags: java, matrices

Estoy intentando recorrer una matriz en Java diagonalmente, empezando por el caracter de la última fila de la primera columna, pero no consigo sacarlo y me estoy volviendo loco. Os dejo el main y lo que yo tengo hecho (que está sin terminar) si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] matriz = {{'p', 'a', 'r', 'p', 'a', 'd', 'o'},
                           {'t', 'i', 'j', 'e', 'r', 'a', 's'},
                           {'f', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'u', 'd', 'o'},
                           {'c', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'l'},
                           {'o', 'm', 'i', 'c', 'r', 'o', 'n'},
                           {'b', 'a', 't', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'a'},
                           {'z', 'a', 'r', 'p', 'a', 'z', 'o'},
        };

        String[] diagonales = Metodos.diagonalesNOSE(matriz);

        if (diagonales != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < diagonales.length; i++)
                System.out.println(diagonales[i]);
    }

public static String[] diagonalesNOSE(char[][] d) {

    //Declarando variables para limites
    int h = d.length; // total filas (eje Y)
    int w = d[0].length; // total columnas (eje x)

    //Comprobando que no sea ni null ni vacia
    for(int f = 0; f < h; f++){
        for(int c = 0; c < w; c++){
            if(d[f][c] == ' ' || h != w){
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    // Si no es vacia...:
    //String []dev = new String[h+w-1]; // Array de strings a devolver
    //String recog = ""; // String que me recoja las diagonales
    ArrayList<String> salida= new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int col = 0; col < w; col++){ // Para que no me cambie de columna hasta que haga todas las filas
        for (int fil = h-1; fil >= 0; fil--){ // Que siga subiendo de filas

            if (col == 0){ // Si estoy en la primera columna
                salida.add(String.valueOf(d[fil][col])); // Cogeme los valores
            }
            if (fil + 1 < h && col + 1 < w){ // Para las siguientes columnas
                salida.add(String.valueOf(d[fil+1][col+1])); // Cogeme los valores de debajo a la izquierda
                System.out.println(salida);
            }
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(recog);
    return null; **me falta cambiar el return y la variable outpur**
```

La salida esperada es: (Recorrer la matriz en direccion Noroeste-Suroeste empezando por abajo a la izquierda):

**z
ba
oar
cmtp
faiaa
terclz
pilarlo
ajpcoa
reuon
prdl
aao
ds
o**

Comment: Y pues, cambia la variable y retórnala. ¿Cuál es la duda?

Comment: y que esperas obtener?

Comment: Pues dada la matriz de arriba debo obtener lo siguiente: '''{z
ba
oar
cmtp
faiaa
terclz
pilarlo
ajpcoa
reuon
prdl
aao
ds
o
}'''

Comment: Nhenon, revisa lo nuevo que puse, modifique el codigo, antes me habia equivocado en la diagonal

Comment: Muchas gracias @Japv lo que pasa es que así solo me recorre la diagonal, y necesito eso, pero que me guarde los elementos que hay en la parte de arriba y debajo de la diagonal, para que me haga una salida as: ''{z ba oar cmtp faiaa terclz pilarlo ajpcoa reuon prdl aao ds o }'' no se si se entiende bien lo que me va cogiendo

Comment: @Nhenon pero eso nunca lo dijiste, ahora es que lo vienes a decir

Comment: @Japv perdona, pensaba que lo había explicado bien, pero tu sabrías hacer eso?

Comment: Entra aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/407618/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-recorrer-una-matriz-de-forma-diagonal-en-java

Comment: @Japv gracias!!

Comment: @Japv sigue sin salirme, no se si me podrías echar una mano, sino no pasa nada, sigo intentándolo xD

Comment: y pq no te sale, cual es el problema?

Comment: Eso es lo que no se, estoy cambiando el codigo pero no consigo que me haga la diagonal que necesito... @Japv voy a cambiar el codigo por el que tengo ahora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Panteamiento**

Se debe recorrer la matriz cuadrada 7x7 a partir del la ultima columna[6][0] e ir recorriendo diagonalmente,tomando los valores y guardarla en un arraylist

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Proceso**

Se tendrán los valores diagonales en el siguiente orden de los indices,tomando como ejemplo una matriz cuadrada 4x4

```
a41     =matriz[3][0]

a31 a42 =matriz[2][0] matriz[3] ['1]
```

**Algoritmo propuesto**

```
static ArrayList<String>  imprimirDiagonalDesc(char matriz[][]){
     //declaramos el arraylist donde guardaremos los valores   
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
     //variable que concatenara los valores diagonales que obtendremos   
        String aux="";
    //Determinamos el tamaño de la matriz
        int d = matriz.length;
    //1 paso :obtener desde el ultimo indice hasta la diagonal media de la matriz
        for (int i = d-1; i>=0; i--) {//ciclo descendente
              int col = i, row = 0;  //declaramos los valores que seran los indices a imprimir
                 while (col < d && row < d) {// mientras ambos indices sean < al tamaño de la matriz
                    aux+=String.valueOf(matriz[col][row]);//concatena los valores diagonales
                    col++;// aumenta columnas matriz[]++
                    row++;// aumenta hilera matriz[][]++
            }
          
           list.add(aux);//se agrega al array
           aux="";//limpiamos la variable para que no sume otros valores diagonales
        }
    //2 paso: apartir de la diagonal media  hasta el primer indice 
    //invertimos la posicion de los indices para imprimir
        for (int j = 0; j < d-1; j++) {
            int row = 0, col = j+1;
                while (row < d && col <d) {
                aux+=String.valueOf(matriz[row][col]);
                col++;
                row++;
            }
            list.add(aux);
            aux="";
        }
        return list;
    }
```

**Resolución**
[Prueba del método](https://rextester.com/NSD40782)

**Salida**

[z, ba, oar, cmtp, faiaa, terclz, pilarlo, ajpcoa, reuon, prdl, aao, ds, o]

Comment: Muchas gracias @Dramaturgo ojalá algún día tener la misma soltura que tu!